# How to use POST_UPDATE git hook on windows

Tags: git, githooks

I'm trying to deploy my project on remote window server by initializing post-update hook file on server repository.
I've created a "git init --bare" repository and renamed post-update-sample hook file to post-update.(i'm using bonobo for git server)
Then i've created my stage repository somewhere else on server and added following line to post-update hook file on bare-git repository :
GIT_WORK_TREE=C:\projects\myproject git checkout -f

on local machine i've added bare-git repo as a remote repository and pushed my project to that server.pushing process done successfully but it seems hook not worked at all..

Now i need help on post-update hook file initializing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time struggling with this problem here is the answer:
git hook files in windows also need to start with "#!/bin/sh" known as shebang in linux world;
after that u could script in batch as usual.